# Using chords to find centre of a circle - getting correct coordinates in one file but wrong coordinates for others

Tags: python, image-processing, fits

I have been attempting to use parallel chords to find the coordinates of the centre of a circle (the sun's disk, in this case).

I have FITS files with data that I have been manipulating, and have written the below code:

```
hdul = fits.open(r'template_file.fits')
header = hdul[0].header
data = hdul[0].data
hdul.close()

y_indices, x_indices = np.where(data >= 6e4) 
#this threshold selects the disk as the intensity is much higher than of the background
```

To 'make' parallel chords, I have decided to put vertical and horizontal lines across the image at intervals of ~200 pixels.

```
def calculate_indices(x_indices, y_indices):
    x_values = range(200, 1201, 200)
    y_values = range(200, 1001, 200)

    # Initialize dictionaries to store the results
    y_1 = {}
    y_2 = {}
    ylen = {}
    x_1 = {}
    x_2 = {}
    xlen = {}

    # Loop over the x values
    for x in x_values:
        # Get the y values corresponding to the current x value
        y_at_x = y_indices[x_indices == x]
        
        # Store the first and last y values and their difference
        y_1[x] = y_at_x[0]
        y_2[x] = y_at_x[-1]
        ylen[x] = y_2[x] - y_1[x]

    # Loop over the y values
    for y in y_values:
        # Get the x values corresponding to the current y value
        x_at_y = x_indices[y_indices == y]
        
        # Store the first and last x values and their difference
        x_1[y] = x_at_y[0]
        x_2[y] = x_at_y[-1]
        xlen[y] = x_2[y] - x_1[y]

    return y_1, y_2, ylen, x_1, x_2, xlen
```

This function returns the points where the line crosses the circle (x1, x2, y1, y2) and the length of each chord (xlen, ylen) for each value in the range y_values, x_values.

I find the radius using this function:

```
def calculate_radius(x_indices):

    left = x_indices.min() #using only x_indices as some images are cut off in the y-direction
    right = x_indices.max()

    r = (right - left)/2

    return r
```

Then, using Pythagoras, it is possible to determine the distance to the centre of the circle using this function:

```
def calculate_results(r, ylen, xlen):
    y_results = {}
    y_vals = range(200, 1201, 200)

    for y in y_vals:
        y_results[y] = y + np.sqrt(r**2 - (ylen[y]/2)**2)

    x_results = {}
    x_vals = range(200, 1001, 200)

    for x in x_vals:
        x_results[x] = x + np.sqrt(r**2 - (xlen[x]/2)**2)
    
    return y_results, x_results
```

I have decided it would be best to take an average of the coordinates to get the central coordinates I require. This is done here:

```
def calculate_average(x_results, y_results): 
    a_values = [200, 400, 600] #arbitrary name
    #only taking the values in the positive hemisphere hence why up to 600

    a = np.array([y_results[a] for a in a_values])
    b = np.array([x_results[a] for a in a_values])

    av_x = np.average(a)
    av_y = np.average(b)

    return av_x, av_y
```

This returns the coordinates I plot.

This appears to work for my template image, but as soon as I apply the same functions to a different file the centre is off.

[image: Here is an image of my template, and the centre that was found using the code above is marked with a blue dot.]

[image: Here is an image of another FITS file of the sun, and you can see that the dot no longer marks the center.]

The only values that are changed is the input data from the FITS file - I don't know what could be causing this issue, as I thought what I had written solves the issue faced by part of the image cutting off.

Can anyone help point out what's going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The first thing I notice is that the sun is perfectly centered in the first image, but not in the second. With some very rough measurements, it appears that the detected center differs by the same off-centering of the sun itself. My guess is that you have a reversed sign on the vertical axis somewhere in your math (i.e. it's pushing the center lower when it should be pushing it higher)

Comment: What do your files look like? I feel like you don't even need to do most of the computation, because if you're assuming diameter to be `x_indices.max() - x.indices.min()` you can just use that to get the centre coordinates (assuming the image is a disk and not ellipse)

Comment: It might help if you shared your images - you can use Google Drive, Dropbox, Github....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have over-complicated the maths and the code a little bit

If you find the first and last white pixel in any row of the image, you can average them and that will give you the x-coordinate of the image centre - as long as the horizontal chord you have drawn is complete, i.e. it doesn't touch the edges of the image.

Likewise, if you find the top-most and bottom-most white pixel in any column of the image, you can average them and that will give you the y-coordinate of the image centre - with same proviso as above.

The proviso about being a complete chord is expressed in this line in the code:

```
if L[x]>0 and R[x]<w
```

I also simplified and hopefully speeded up the code using Numpy to do the processing. You should consider trying to avoid iterating over pixels with `for` loops - they are slow and error-prone.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

# Load the image, greyscale and threshold at 128 to Boolean mask of sun's pixels
BGR  = cv.imread('image.png')
grey = cv.cvtColor(BGR, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
mask = grey > 128
h, w = grey.shape

# Get left-most and right-most True pixel in each row
# Get top-most and bottom-most True pixel in each column
L = np.argmax(mask, axis=1)
R = w - np.argmax(mask[..., ::-1], axis=1)
T = np.argmax(mask, axis=0)
B = h - np.argmax(mask[::-1, ...], axis=0)

# Get midpoint between left and right only for rows that are complete chords
xcentres = [ (L[x]+R[x])/2 for x in range(h) if L[x]>0 and R[x]<w ]
x = int(np.mean(xcentres))
# Get midpoint between top and bottom only for columns that are complete chords
ycentres = [ (T[x]+B[x])/2 for x in range(h) if T[x]>0 and B[x]<h ]
y = int(np.mean(ycentres))

print(f'{x=}, {y=}')

# Draw centre in red
BGR[y-3:y+3, x-3:x+3] = [0,0,255]
cv.imwrite('result.png', BGR)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! It works! I think I'll be able to align my images from there - I really appreciate your help with the chord conditions especially, I think that was my main issue :)

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project.